# Android Network Location

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location, user-experience

While 'location' us disabled on Android none of GPS or Network locations are available.

Unfortunately location is an important feature for a product we are working on, but the sub km accuracy not. So we developed few scripts that are working with Google CID and WiFi based location system that is either quite precise (30mt urban area).

While testing the UX we discover that actually more than 90% of users are allways worried to keep location on (allmost none of them for privacy reasons). 
- They link the meaning of location to GPS and they are worried of power consumption, either if we are not turning on the GPS.
- As far as they keep location on and forgot about it (as there is not satellite symbol blinking over there) they will remember to turn it off as soon as they open another of those applications that start heavily using GPS while available.

We were thinking for last few days about all possible solutions to improve UX becouse of that network and GPS location are set together by a single toggle that people still turning off.

I'm asking have you ever face this problem that user will offer you all the locations you need, because you are using it rationally, but you still losing this information because the negative feedback other APPs are giving to the user while loc is on? Have you ever figured out with a solution?